# Changing Gmail account belonging to my Google+ account

Tags: gmail, google-plus, google-account

I've had the same Gmail account now for 5+ years. I have a Google+ account associated with that Gmail account. I want to change my email address, so I created a new Gmail account.  How do I associate it with my Google+ profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. Here is the error that I received.

[image: Error Message]![enter image description here]

And the full page in the settings menu.
[image: Full page]

Answer (score 2):

As you're creating a new GMail account anyway you *can* do this, but you have to do it from the Google+ end.

Click on the "Mail" link:

[image: Click on Mail]

and you'll be redirected to this page where you can create a **new** GMail account which will be associated with your Google+ account:

[image: Enter new account details]

It means you'll create *another* new GMail account, but as you're doing that anyway you can just abandon the first "new" account you created.